# If Statement To Match A String Containing Double Quotations

Tags: string, bash, if-statement, grep, double-quotes

I've an issue with an if statement in my bash script. 
The goal: I need to check a value of `clustered`, but since it's not a unique name, I decided to try to match the whole string. For example, to find if `clustered` is true/false here, the `if` looks for the whole "neighboring" string.

The issue: while the `if` statement below works fine for some strings, it actually doesnt work with the values below. I suspect it's because of the double quotations around `"false"`.

Is it possible to change this `if`, so it will work (i.e. accept the additional double quotations)?

My bash:

```
if grep -Fxq "<cache clustered="false" " confg.xml
then
    echo "Correct value"
    # code if found
else
    echo "Incorrect value"
    # code if not found
fi
```

Thank you,

Comment: Use single quotes around the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using double quotes around the string you are grepping for, as well as in the string itself.  Bash interprets quotes by matching each double quote with the next double quote, not the last.  If quotes were parentheses, your first line would look like `if grep -Fxq (<cache clustered=)false( ) confg.xml` when what you really want is `if grep -Fxq (<cache clustered=(false) ) confg.xml`.  In other words, the internal double quotes aren't interpreted as literal double quotes.  If you want them to be interpreted literally, enclose your grep expression in single quotes rather than double quotes:

```
if grep -Fxq '<cache clustered="false" ' confg.xml
```

Comment: Or, in the general case, use adjacent strings with different quotes. `"foo'"'"bar'` properly quotes the string `foo'"bar` -- that's `foo'` in double quotes adjacent to `"bar` in single quotes.

Comment: A fun alternative way to put a double quote literally inside double quotes:  `"blah blah blah "'"'"quote"'"'" blah blah"`, which is `blah blah blah ` in double quotes, followed by `"` in single quotes, followed by `blah blah` in double quotes.  It will be interpreted as `blah blah blah "quote" blah blah`

Comment: `"<cache clustered=\"false\" "` seems simpler (than anything except the single-quoted version). BTW, +1 for a nice explanation of nesting and the lack thereof.

Comment: Hey, thank you all for the replies, it's very appreciated. I went with the single quotes solution, since it was the simplest one to implement.

Answer (score 1):

tried this, seems to work fine

```
bash$ cat log; if grep -Fxq "<cache clustered=\"false\"" log ; then echo "got it"; else echo "missed"; fi
<cache clustered="false"
got it
```

the inside double quotes need to be taken as literal. So the backslash ahead of them informs the bash they are not starting or ending of a string

Comment: Hey,
thank you all for the replies, it's very appreciated. I went with the single quotes solution, since it was the simplest one to implement.